# Exception: The plugin firebase_admob could not be built due to the issue above

Tags: flutter, dart, admob, firebase-admob

i have a problems
this bug appears when i add the plugin "  firebase_admob: ^0.11.0+1" in pubspec.yaml

> > FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>
> > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> > Android resource linking failed
> > /home/mohamed/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/804bb16bf16b5e91bc08a39b6997ce12/play-services-ads-lite-19.6.0/AndroidManifest.xml:27:5-38:15:
> > AAPT: error: unexpected element  found in . 2
>
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 10s The built failed likely due to AndroidX
> incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetfier
> to solve the incompatibility. Building plugin firebase_admob...
> Exception: The plugin firebase_admob could not be built due to the
> issue above. Exited (sigterm)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eU31q.png)

gradle.proprieties

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
android.enableR8=true
```

build.gradle :

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.admob10"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I too solved the issue by upgrading build gradle version.

- previous setting in `build.gradle` file of project was:

  ```
  classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0")
  ```
- current setting:

  ```
  classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.4")
  ```

The issue was gone immediately. :)