# BUILD FAILED in Flutter Project

Tags: android, flutter, build-error

Launching lib\main.dart on Mi A1 in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> Android resource linking failed
> C:\Users\anand.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\9d2250f2160023e86dcf90b2c8c1bc31\core-1.7.0-beta01\res\values\values.xml:105:5-114:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/lStar not found.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 57s
The build failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetifier to solve the incompatibility.
Building plugin admob_flutter...
√ Built build\app\outputs\repo.
Building plugin agora_rtc_engine...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\agora_rtc_engine-4.0.7\android\build.gradle' line: 29
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'agora_rtc_engine'.

> Plugin with id 'com.android.library' not found.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s

Exception: The plugin agora_rtc_engine could not be built due to the issue above.
Exited (sigterm)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exception: The plugin firebase\_admob could not be built due to the issue above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65857643/exception-the-plugin-firebase-admob-could-not-be-built-due-to-the-issue-above)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.